# How can I handle manual scrolling alongside auto-scroll feature which is creating issues?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've implemented a Banner auto scroll feature(React native) as well as manual scroll, But I'm facing an issue and I've spend days to fix and searching for solution but nothing helps!

Here is my code :

```
import React, {
  memo,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useState,
  useCallback,
} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import Item from './Item';
import {clientQuery} from 'apolloClient/index';
import KEYS from 'apolloClient/constants';
import {useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {useApp} from 'provider/Main';

const screen = Dimensions.get('screen');
type TBannerProps = {
  GET_KEY: (typeof KEYS)[keyof typeof KEYS];
};

const Index = (props: TBannerProps) => {
  const {updateValue} = useApp();
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const scrollRef: any = useRef(null);
  const {GET_KEY} = props;

  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const fetchBanner = useCallback(async () => {
    updateValue('showLoadingModel', true);
    const {data, error} = await clientQuery(GET_KEY);
    if (!error) {
      if (data?.getBannerSettingList?.length) {
        setResult(data.getBannerSettingList);
      }
    }
    updateValue('showLoadingModel', false);
  }, [GET_KEY, updateValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused && !result.length) {
      fetchBanner();
    }
  }, [fetchBanner, isFocused, result]);

  const autoScroll = useCallback(
    (value: number) => {
      if (scrollRef?.current) {
        scrollRef.current.Timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          if (value < result.length - 1) {
            autoScroll(value + 1);
          } else {
            autoScroll(0);
          }
          scrollRef?.current?.scrollTo({
            x: (screen.width - 47) * value,
            animated: true,
          });
        }, 4000);
      }
    },
    [result.length],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (result.length) {
      autoScroll(1);
    }

    return () => {
      if (scrollRef?.current?.Timeout) {
        clearTimeout(scrollRef?.current?.Timeout);
      }
    };
  }, [autoScroll, result]);

  const scrollBlock = useMemo(
    () => (
      <ScrollView
        ref={scrollRef}
        style={page.scrollView}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        pinchGestureEnabled={true}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}>
        <View style={page.myElement}>
          {result.map((item: any) => {
            if (item?.category?.banner) {
              return (
                <Item
                  key={item.id}
                  name={item.category.name}
                  banner={item.category.banner['banner-1']}
                />
              );
            }
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    ),
    [result],
  );

  if (!result.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return scrollBlock;
};

const page = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginTop: 15,
  },

  myElement: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});

export default memo(Index);
```

**Problem overview:** When I manually scroll to other banner, auto scroll feature behaves strangely example, I've slided 3 banners and meanwhile auto scroll feature will move me back to 1st banner. Due to this, It works unexpectedly.

I've spend days in searching to grab the active slide so that I can update auto scroll, but nothing works/nor I found anything helpful and Now I'm stuck on this.

I need help to get the active slide index when manually sliding, or any other solution which will solve my issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the `onScroll`-event of `ScrollView`? You would get at least a content-offset information every frame. https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll

Comment: Correct me if wrong, So you are suggesting making a calculation method based on offset?  Right and based on that I should get an index value to handle it?

Comment: I tried it but I didn't get an index, But I think I'll try with offset, but I believe this offset logic could be problematic as with the offset, I need to keep in mind the device width too as every device has different dimensions.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you do not get an index. You have to use the `onLayout`-property in each Banner with `event.nativeEvent.layout` to get the x- and y-coordinates. BUT: onLayout only fires on first render, as far as I know. So if your banners are changing in between, it may mess up the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll wait for some other solutions/approaches if I get them from the community, otherwise, I'll try the offset approach and will dig into it.